# Ember bind controller attribute to hbs template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember template/hbs, I have the following code;

```
{{#my-accordion accordionPanels=myPanels.accordionPanels as |accordion|}}
{{/my-accordion}}
```

Also in my backing controller js, after some AJAX processing, I do

```
self.set('myPanels', myPanels);
```

Now for some reasons, it seems that the controller attribute which I am setting is not getting tied to the hbs file

The only thing is the attribute is not available instantly and I have to do some AJAX processing to set the data & at the end of that, I am setting myPanels

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming perhaps `myPanels` is more than a container for `accordionPanels`, then you could create a computed property for `accordionPanels`:

```
accordionPanels: Ember.computed('myPanels', function() {
    return this.get('myPanels.accordionPanels');
}
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#my-accordion accordionPanels=accordionPanels}}
{{/my-accordion}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing exactly correct and it should work. You can cross check `self` refers to controller and `myPanels` contains proper data using `console.log(self,myPanels)`

**controllers\application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({   
    myPanels:{accordionPanels:[1,2]},

    init(){
        this._super(...arguments);
        //For illustration purpose 
        Ember.run.later((() => {
             console.log('init emer run callback ',this);
             this.set('myPanels',{accordionPanels:[3,4,5]});
         }),5000);
    },    
});
```

**templates\application.hbs**

```
{{#my-accordion accordionPanels=myPanels.accordionPanels as |accordion|}}   
 From Child :{{accordion}} <br/>
 From Parent: {{myPanels.accordionPanels}}
{{/my-accordion}}

{{outlet}}
```

**templates\components\my-accordion.hbs**

```
{{yield accordionPanels}}
```